# how can I plot a Cox model with ~pspline and find the cutoff in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am now learning how to evaluate a non-linear association between X and Y. And I find package 'smoothHR' is a good choice.
for example, I want to evaluate the non-linear association between HDLC and event

```
model<-coxph(Surv(futime, death) ~ age+sex+pspline(hdlc,df = 2), data = data,x=T)
hr1 <- smoothHR(data=data, coxfit=model)
print(hr1)
plot(hr1,predictor='hdlc',prob = 0,conf.level=0.95,round.x = 1)
```

finally, I get a plot like:

[image: this]

And I have 2 questions

1. How can I change Y aixs to Hazard ratio (HR)
2. How can I find the optimal cutoff——the intersection of 95% confident interval curve and the line y = 1

just like:

[image: this]

and

[image: this]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

load the libraries

```
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
```

get the lung data

```
df = lung
```

model Cox model using penalised spline term for age

```
c = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ pspline(age, df = 4), data = df)
```

using term plot, we can get the coefficients for age
plot = F so that we can get the data

```
g = termplot(c, term = 1, se = T,plot = F)

newdf = data.frame(g$age)
```

now the newdf dataframe contains x = age, y = log(hr) and se = standard error
for the log(HR)
we can use exp(y +/- 1.96se) to get the CI (95%) that we want
use log(HR) = HR instead and then plot

I have used base R but to make a more beautiful plot, we can use the same
concept and plot this with ggplot2.
this is a dataframe with the new variables hr, lci and uci added to the
original dataframe. So it is very easy to use ggplot2 to get the same
figure as in base R.

```
plot(x = newdf$x, y = newdf$hr,type = 'l', col = "red",xlab = "Age",
     ylab = "Hazard ratio for Age with the Cox model using psplines")
lines(x = newdf$x, y = newdf$lci, col = "blue")
lines(x = newdf$x, y = newdf$uci, col = "blue")
abline(h = 1, col = "gray")
```

Comment: These plots and many more can be done more easily with the rms and Hmisc package by Frank Harrell. He also has a book "Regression Modelling Strategies" - https://www.amazon.com/Regression-Modeling-Strategies-Applications-Statistics/dp/0387952322. The book is excellent in that it gives examples for each type of regression model and how to graph it. It is now redone with ggplot2 graphics. He also has a very active blog and website that you can check out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I try to plot it by 'ggplot2' and it really solved my first question.
But how can I mark the intersection of lines(x = newdf$x, y = newdf$lci) and abline(h = 1), just like the '107','154' in the figure 3 above.

Comment: In addition, I have learned about 'rms' before and try to build a piecewise cox regression using 'rcs', but it can not find the point with minimum hazard ratio(like '1.5' in the figure 1 above). 
Then I find 'smoothHR' can find the point with minimum hazard ratio refer to article 10.1136/bmj.k2158.
So, whether I can determine the point with minimum hazard ratio by 'rms'?
Thanks again and looking forward to your reply!

Comment: It is very easy with ggplot2 to add layers to your graph. So, using geom_vline and geom_hline, you can create vertical or horizontal lines on your original graph. The easiest way is to create the first graph and give it a name 'g'. Then you can use g1 = g + geom_vhline(yintercept = 1) to make the horizontal line at HR = 1.